# Which column matched?

Tags: php, mysql

How do I know which column matched if I have two `LIKE` clauses for two different columns and eventually one of the two columns contains the needle.

Comment: You need to post your code too.

Answer (score 1):

you could do something like:

```
SELECT 1 AS `match`, * FROM `table` WHERE col1 LIKE 'needle%'
UNION 
SELECT 2 AS `match`, * FROM `table` WHERE col2 LIKE 'needle%'
```

and use `match` to know

Note: this could probably be written with a `IF()`

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT
  IF(col1 LIKE 'needle%' AND col2 LIKE 'needle%', 0, IF(col1 LIKE 'needle%', 1, 2)
    AS match, 
  *
FROM
  table
WHERE
  col1 LIKE 'needle%'
OR
  col2 LIKE 'needle%'
```

`match` teklls you which colums hit:

- 0 = both
- 1 = match on `col1`
- 2 = match on `col2`

Answer (score 0):

You can use your PHP section to check which one matched.

```
if (stristr($result['col1'], $queryvar) === true) // col1 matched
```